# Changing src after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, while-loop, settimeout

I am trying to change the src attribute of an image with the class of "bg" after 3 seconds on a loop. It goes from "bg1.jpg" to "bg5.jpg". For some reason my code is not working and I am not getting any errors.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var $bg = $('.bg');

function bgChange() {
  var i = 1;
  while ( i < 6 ) {
    var background = '<?php echo $siteroot; ?>/img/bg' + i + '.jpg';
    setTimeout($bg.attr('src', background), 1000);
    i++;
    if ( i === 5 ) {
      i = 1;
    }
  }
}

bgChange();
//------------------------------------
});
```

Comment: So, you have PHP in your JavaScript file, I'm guessing your JavaScript file isn't being served via your PHP processor? -- unless your JavaScript is inline.

Comment: ...also setTimeout is being called in an infinite loop!  while(i < 6) {if (i === 5) i = 1}

Comment: setTimeout won't do anything at all, until your JavaScript has finished doing stuff.  The calls are queued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `src` one by one with interval time so don't use `while || for` loops.

Try this example with `setTimeout()`

```
var $bg = $('.bg');

function bgChange(i) {
  if(i == 6)i = 1; // reset
  var background = '<?php echo $siteroot; ?>/img/bg' + i + '.jpg';
  $bg.attr('src', background); // change src
  setTimeout(function(){bgChange(i++)}, 3000); // call again after 3 sec
}

bgChange(1);
```

Comment: This worked once I took the php out as @Lee Kowalkowski recommended. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setInterval()` to do that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // run background change function
  bgChange(5); // 5 is number of images
});

// functions
function bgChange(num_of_images) {
  var $bg = $('.bg');
  var i = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
      i = (i < num_of_images) ? i + 1 : 1; 
      var background = '<?php echo $siteroot; ?>/img/bg' + i + '.jpg';
      $bg.attr('src', background);
  } , 3000);
}
```

**Test Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // run background change function
  bgChange(5); // 5 is number of images
});

// functions
function bgChange(num_of_images) {
  var $bg = $('.bg');
  var i = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
    i = (i < num_of_images) ? i+1 : 1; 
   /*
      var background = '<?php echo $siteroot; ?>/img/bg' + i + '.jpg';
      $bg.attr('src', background);
    */
    $bg.html('bg'+i);
    
  } , 3000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">bg1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting all the timers at once.

If it does anything(Which I'm not sure it does, seeing it's not a function body), it will wait 1000ms before calling the function 5 times at once for then to never call the function again.

What you can do is a function that will call itself after a delay, have a look at the snippet.

```js
var imageRoot = "/images/backgrounds/"
var backgrounds = [
  "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg",
  "http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg",
  "http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/desktop-year-of-the-tiger-images-wallpaper.jpg",
  imageRoot + "bg4.jpg",
  imageRoot + "bg5.jpg",  
]
function UpdateImageBackground(i, images) {
  // Make sure i doesn't go past images.length
  i = i%images.length;
  
  var bgs = document.getElementsByClassName("bg");
  for(var j=0; j<bgs.length; j++) {
    bgs[j].src = images[i];
  }
  
  // Call itself again after 3000 miliseconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    UpdateImageBackground(i+1, images);
  }, 3000);
}
UpdateImageBackground(0, backgrounds);
```

```html
<img class="bg" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var $bg = $('.bg')
  var root = '<?php echo $siteroot; ?>'
  var i = 0

  function bgChange() {
    var background = root + '/img/bg' + (++i) + '.jpg'
    console.log(background)
    $bg.attr('src', background)
    i %= 6
    setTimeout(bgChange, 1000)
  }

  bgChange()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -2):

1. declare your function.
2. setInterval and reference your function

```
var index = 1;
function bgChange(){
    if(index == 6){
        index = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("image").src = "bg" + num + ".jpg";
    index += 1;
}
var i = setInterval(bgChange, 3000);
```

Comment: you mean setTimeout()

Comment: @magreenberg Hmm? `setTimeout` only executes once.

Comment: My code works for me. In fact, I do just the exact same thing. I have a function to modify the src attrb of a img tag.  Edited to show how i acomplish that